# How to assign records to resource dynamically with Angular

Tags: mysql, angular, lumen, api-design

I'm trying to implement a requirement/feature in an application I'm building and I'm struggling to implement it. I'm using Angular 6 to build the UI, Lumen for the API and MYSQL for the persistence layer.

**The requirement is:**

- There is collection of regular users and admin users.
- There is a collection of "skills".
- Admin users can "assign" "skills" to users.
- Admin users can add/edit/delete the master list of "skills".

**My current plan so far:**

- Create "skills" database table to store all the skills names and ID.
- Create "skills_users" database table to store all assigned skills to respective users.
- Create endpoint to return all "skills" from database table as they will be dynamic values.
- Create endpoint for user resource that takes an array property named "skills" that contains the IDs of all the "skills" to be assigned to a specific user.

The bit I'm struggling with is the UI for the assigning of the "skills" to users. The UI will need to request the list of all the "skills" and dynamically display them on the page as checkbox fields in a form (that bit I can do). But then I need a way to use that dynamically generated form that uses checkbox fields to construct the new payload and I'm not quite sure how to do that.

This the HTML code I've got so far, but it's not complete as I can't work out how to complete it:

```
<div class="mb-1" *ngFor="let additional_skill of additional_skills; let i = index">
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="skills[i]" name="{{ additional_skill.id }}">{{ additional_skill.name }}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated, I hope I've explained myself well enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a click event handler on mat-checkbox and push every clicked skill to an array. Than you can build an object with two properties, for example, id (id of a user that we want to associate with skills) and selected_skills array that you have and save that. Something like this:

skills.component.html

```
<div class="mb-1" *ngFor="let additional_skill of additional_skills;>
    <mat-checkbox (click)="selectSkill(additional_skill.skill_id)" name="{{ additional_skill.id }}"> 
       {{additional_skill.name }}
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>

<button (click)="saveUserSkills()">Save skills for this user</button>
```

skills.component.ts

```
skills = [];
userId = 25; // lets assume that this is id of a user that we want to "upgrade"

selectSkill(skillId: number) {
    this.skills.push(skillId);
}

saveUserSkills(){
    let payload = {
        id: this.id,
        selected_skills: this.skills
    };

    this._userSkillsService.saveSkills(payload)
        .then(response => {
            ...
        })
        .catch(err => {
            ...
        })
}
```

Hope this was helpfull!